# Regex Negation for Inventory.py in ansible

Tags: python, regex, ansible, ansible-inventory

I would need a help in negating a particular string in my ansible playbook .

I want to exclude the servers which has tag  apps as haproxy. Not sure how to arrive this with regular expression .
I tried the following , which is not working

Requirement:
1. Get all the servers which has Environment as qa
2. But exclude the haproxy servers.

```
1.tag_Environment_qa:!&tag_apps_*haproxy*"

2.tag_apps_(?<!*haproxy*):&tag_Environment_qa
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the text and what the ouput should be? just to make sure we get the right Idea

Answer (score 0):

Please check below, is this what you need?

```
- name: get qa servers tag
  command: some command to get tag
  register: tag
- name: exclude the haproxy servers
  command: some command
  when: "'haproxy' not in tag.stdout"
```